# Unable to read Storage account and key - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload image to Blob. Hence in the Web.Config I have settings like this:

```
            <appSettings>
                <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
                <add key="StorageAccountName" value="storageaccount1"/> 
                <add key="StorageAccountKey" value="storageaccountkey1"/>
              </appSettings>
```

Here is how it looks like in the portal:

[image]

My Dot Net code is as below:

```
        public class ConnectionString
            {
                static string account = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountName");
                static string key = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountKey");
                public static CloudStorageAccount GetConnectionString()
                {
                    string connectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", account, key);
                    return CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
                }
            }
```

However, my "account" and "key" variable are returning NULL.

Could any one please suggest, what I'm doing wrong? Is there anything that I'm missing?

Note: I'm able to upload image via "Azure Storage Explorer".

Comment: Does the problem happen locally ? On Azure ? Do you check that you have these settings in your config file or on the portal app settings blade ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccountName");`should work If you config it in the **Web.config** file. I test it with Asp.net MVC file. It works correctly on my side.

[image]

**Test Result:**

[image]

```
CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("MySetting")
```

> Which will read values from all the configuration files i.e., app.config, web.config and ServiceConfiguration.cscfg.

**Note:** If we config the appsetting in the **Web.Debug.config** not web.config file,it will get null value.

Answer (score 0):

To read web.config file, please use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`. `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()` is used to read .cscfg file actually.

Comment: In my experience, `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()` will fall back and read either `app.config` or `web.config` if there is no `.cscfg` file.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. I was using web.config that is under view (which is wrong). No .Net code changed. By using correct web.config solved the problem.